# Is there any pattern in this two-dimensional array?

Tags: pattern-recognition

```
1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9

1  3  2   5   3   7   4   9   5

1  4  5   2   7   8   3  10  11

1  5  6   7   2   9  10  11   3

1  6  7   8   9   2  11  12  13

1  7  8   9  10  11   2  13  14

1  8  9  10  11  12  13   2  15
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by law? You want to find a pattern?

Comment: @user37238 Yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row numbers are increment by leaving 1 extra space in every row. like
first row `1.2.3.4...`.
Second row `1.x.2.x3...`.
third row `1.x.x2.x.x.3..`.
where as column number increments  at the place of x.

**Row is working like this**

```
1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9

1  x  2   x   3   x   4   x   5

1  x  x   2   x   x   3   x   x

1  x  x   x   2   x   x   x   3

1  x  x   x   x   2   x   x   x

1  x  x   x   x   x   2   x   x

1  x  x   x   x   x   x   2   x
```

**Column value is just increment at the place of x**
increment up to down.

```
z  2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9

z  3  z   5   z   7   z   9   z

z  4  5   z   7   8   z  10  11

z  5  6   7   z   9  10  11   z

z  6  7   8   9   z  11  12  13

z  7  8   9  10  11   z  13  14

z  8  9  10  11  12  13   z  15
```

Comment: Thank you so much,it becomes quite simple after given an explanation! Forgive my silliness!

Comment: @walter you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the fractions $i/j$ in a regular, square array.
Put each fraction in lowest terms, so 5/5 becomes 1/1.
The number in the array is the sum of the numerator and denominator.